# Geometric meaning of homology/cohomology over constant sheaf

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

As in the title, I would like to have some geometric intuition or a dictionary from things appeared in algebraic geometry to terms in algebraic topology (I had some studies in algebraic geometry but I am quite new to algebraic topology). In algebraic geometry, we sometimes consider cohomology over constant sheaf.

For instance, Chern class of a line bundle is an element in the cohomology group $H^2(X,\mathbb{Z})$. At some examples that I recall, algebraic geometers also consider cohomology group over constant sheafs like $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{Q}$.

I would like to ask are there a correspondences cohomology over constant sheafs to homology/cohomology that we studied in algebraic topology, like to simplicial, singular and celluar homology?

Thanks in advance for answering.

Comment: For nice spaces, sheaf cohomology with coefficients in the constant sheaf $\underline{G}$ is isomorphic to singular (or whatever ordinary coh. theory you prefer) cohomology with coefficients in the group $G$. Unfortunately, algebraic geometry doesn't deal much with "nice spaces." If you've seen Chern classes defined as taking values on integral cohomology, presumably you're looking at complex varieties where you can use the Euclidean topology to compute...

Comment: ...Outside of this setting, however, you only have the Zariski topology which doesn't give you the "right" answer (i.e. if $X$ is a smooth curve of genus $g$, $H^1(X,\underline{G})$ should be a free $G$-module of rank $2g$ as happens on Riemann surfaces). Grothendieck et al. spent much of the 1950s and 60s figuring out how to rectify this.

Comment: @TabesBridges explicitly, what do you mean by "nice space"?

Comment: It's a deliberately vague phrase. Certainly compact, oriented manifolds work. Maybe CW complexes as well (or at least finitely presented CW complexes), but I've never actually studied sheaf cohomology on a CW complex.

Comment: To elaborate a bit: the model example is the threefold isomorphism between singular cohomology (or your favorite ordinary cohomology theory) with $\mathbb R$ coefficients, de Rham cohomology, and the Cech cohomology of the constant sheaf $\underline{\mathbb R}$. The moral of at least part of the story is that a compact manifold can be covered by a finite collection of contractible open sets, and de Rham and Cech cohomology are trivial on contractible opens (i.e. for de Rham this is the Poincare lemma)...

Comment: ...so cohomology is determined by the lattice formed by the opens and there intersections, their 3-fold intersections, and so on. In contrast, a complex affine variety is almost never Euclidian-contractible, so you will lose information trying to carry out the same idea in the Zariski topology: for $X$ an algebraic curve and $p \ne q$ points, $(X\setminus {p}) \cup (X\setminus {q})$ is an affine cover. Since this works as well for curves of positive genus as for $\mathbb P^1$, we see that "the combinatorics of the Zariski cover" fail to tell us much of anything.